# Qual é a diferença entre x-www-form-urlencoded e form-data?

Tags: http, http-headers

Existe alguma diferença relevante entre os `content-type` `x-www-form-urlencoded` e `form-data`?

Sempre tenho dúvidas quando devo usar entre um ou outro, por não saber se existe alguma diferença impactante.

Comment: @Edilson só me explica uma coisa: aquele `form-data` que aparece no postman é a mesma coisa que `multipart/formdata`? Se for, vou excluir a pergunta . kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk

Comment: O que é postman ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Esses content-type especifica como os dados do formuário devem ser codificados ao serem enviados para o servidor (somente quando method="post")

Para `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, o corpo da mensagem HTTP enviada para o servidor é essencialmente uma seqüência de consulta, nome / valor são separados pelo comercial (&), e os nomes são separados dos valores usando igual (=). Um exemplo disto seria:

Nome=rafael&cidade=campinas&idade=31

Isso significa que para cada byte não alfanumérico que existe em um dos nossos valores, que vai levar três bytes para representá-lo. Para grandes arquivos binários, triplicando a carga vai ser altamente ineficiente.

É aí que `multipart/form-data` entra. Com este método de transmissão de pares nome / valor, cada par é representado como uma "parte" em uma mensagem MIME (como descrito por outras respostas). As peças são separadas por uma  seqüência particular (escolhida especificamente para que esta cadeia não ocorre em qualquer um dos "valor"). 
Cada parte tem seu próprio conjunto de cabeçalhos MIME como Content-Type, e particularmente Content-Disposition, que pode dar a cada parte o seu "nome". O valor de cada pedaço de par nome / valor é a carga útil de cada parte da mensagem MIME. 
A especificação MIME nos dá mais opções quando representando o valor da carga útil - nós podemos escolher uma codificação mais eficiente de dados binários para economizar largura de banda (por exemplo base 64 ou mesmo binário simples).

Por que não usar multipart / form-data o tempo todo? Para valores alfanuméricos curtos (como a maioria dos formulários da web), a sobrecarga de adicionar todos os cabeçalhos MIME vai superam significativamente qualquer poupança de codificação binária mais eficiente.

A moral da história é, se você tiver dados binários (não-alfanumérico) (ou uma carga de tamanho significativamente) para transmitir, usar multipart / form-data. Caso contrário, a aplicação de uso / x-www-form-urlencoded.

fonte: https://gist.github.com/joyrexus/524c7e811e4abf9afe56