# O que esta linha significa? --> $.ajaxSetup({ scriptCharset: "utf-8" ,contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" })

Tags: jquery, ajax

Olá, estou analisando uma programação já feita para aprender, está dando certo, porém cheguei nesta parte e não estou encontrando online o significado dela.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Segue a linha de código:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ scriptCharset: "utf-8" ,contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" })
```

Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

São apenas configurações de conexão ajax contendo especificações sobre o tipo de charset e o conteudo que serão trafegados no HTTP request.

Para compreender melhor sobre os argumentos definidos nessa função, você terá que estudar um pouco sobre a estrutura do protocolo HTTP (Seria interessante pesquisar seu derivado também, que é o TCP), mas em resumo, o código acima só especifica o content Type e o tipo de dado que será passado na requisição.

Links interessantes:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields
- [Qual é a diferença entre x-www-form-urlencoded e form-data?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103157/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-x-www-form-urlencoded-e-form-data)

Answer (score 1):

Essa linha define uma configuração padrão para futuras requisições AJAX que serão realizadas via jQuery.

Ao invés de definir esses assets em todas as chamadas, você os determina previamente e economiza algumas linhas quando necessitar realizar as requisições.

A página do método na documentação do jQuery dá alguns exemplos sobre: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/